# Accidentally mounted /boot on my data partition during Timeshift recovery

Tags: linux, mount, boot, partition

let me start by stating my setup:
I've got a root partition taking a whole SSD drive (sdb). The second one, a HDD is split between a Windows partition (sda2) and a data mount (sda1), like this:

```
sda                               8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                            8:1    0 465,8G  0 part  /run/timeshift/backup
│                                                          /home/hdd1tb
│                                                          /boot
└─sda2                            8:2    0 465,8G  0 part  
sdb                               8:16   0 476,9G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                            8:17   0 476,9G  0 part  
  └─luks-56799420-9e5f-40d0-9b94-01f4f9c0451d
```

The gist of the issue is that I messed up my system by removing some dependency, and I had a Timeshift backup from which I restored it back to normal. However, I might have messed up the process somehow, in that I moved the /boot to my data mount (sda1), which promptly started hogging on the whole free space, making that partition useless.

```
/dev/sda1       458G  427G  7,8G  99% /boot
```

What would be the way for me to get out of this mess? I seem to recall /boot had it's own separate place, instead of being there on the data drive.

Comment: That diagram indicates that sda1 is mounted as 3 different mountpoints (none of which is your root mountpoint).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first thing is to figure out how your partition layout is supposed to look, which probably involves going through each of your partitions and checking what's on them. You might want to do that by connecting the drive to another machine so that your partitions aren't mounted while you investigate.

I'm not sure how you have /dev/sda1 mounted on multiple paths unless it's using LVM or you have symlinks or something. If you actually have the same filesystem mounted in multiple locations that would definitely explain things being a bit odd. If you have symlinks, they might have been broken by the restore process somehow.

Basically it'll be a painstaking process of working out exactly where things ought to be and updating your configuration to mount the right partition in the right place. You may find you want to copy data off, repartition and copy it back.